# Clojure: Execution error (SQLException) at java.sql.DriverManager/getConnection (DriverManager.java:702)

Tags: postgresql, clojure

When evaluating, i get the following error:

Execution error (SQLException) at java.sql.DriverManager/getConnection (DriverManager.java:702).

```
(ns postgres
  (:require [clojure.java.jdbc :as sql])
  )


(println "test")


(def db-spec
  {:dbtype "postgresql"
   :dbname "test"
   :user "dave"
   :password "mypass"})

(defn all-tasks []
  (sql/query db-spec ["SELECT * FROM hello"]))


(all-tasks)
```

My deps.edn looks like this:

```
{
 :paths ["test" "src"]
 :deps {clojure.java-time/clojure.java-time {:mvn/version "0.3.2"}
        org.clojure/java.jdbc {:mvn/version "0.7.12"}
        com.stuartsierra/component {:mvn/version "1.1.0"}
        }
 }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the database-specific JDBC driver to your `:deps`.

Neither `clojure.java.jdbc` (the old, stable, no longer being enhanced library) nor `next.jdbc` (the modern, well-maintained replacement) provide actual JDBC drivers -- they exist as Clojure wrappers for "generic" JDBC itself.

See https://github.com/seancorfield/next-jdbc/blob/develop/deps.edn for examples of JDBC drivers that `next.jdbc` has been tested against and https://github.com/clojure/java.jdbc/blob/master/deps.edn for examples of JDBC drivers that `clojure.java.jdbc` has been tested against (which are generally older and some still provide Java 7 support).

For PostgreSQL, you'll want some version of:

```
org.postgresql/postgresql {:mvn/version "42.4.1"}
```

If you are just getting started with Clojure, I strongly recommend you use `next.jdbc` instead of the older library. Aside from the maintenance status of c.j.j, the documentation for `next.jdbc` is much better and that's where I'm putting all of my effort these days -- I'm only providing critical security fixes for c.j.j at this point.